# Why does TypeScript allow this?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I'm making a GET request that results in a JS object like this:

```js
// Note: The variable is not actually declared and hardcoded like this
// This is just to demonstrate what the received object looks like
let obj = {id: "1"};
```

And I also have the following class:

```js
export class Test {
    constructor(public id: number) { }
}
```

I then create a new instance of this class like so:

```js
let aClass = new Test(obj.id);
```

And to my surprise, the instance is created just fine. At first I thought "Cool! It's automatically trying to cast the id to a number!" but that isn't the case, and that's confusing me a bit.

```js
console.log(typeof aClass.id);
```

Reveals that the id is of type string. I stubbornly refused to believe that, and tried:

```js
console.log(aClass.id += 12);
```

And as I should have expected at this point, it appended "12" to the string.

Now, my question is: **why does this happen and why doesn't it throw an error instead?**

Comment: Example you have mentioned on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgVhAvBA3gSwCYC4ICICMuAvgNwCwAUJQMbACGAzgxACogOQqUQ8TVQA7DgCcArtTBRhACgAOomMDTUImHANEBbGCGEBKVBCKVjVCqEhh2kZAJAB3Vtemw4AOkx6SQA). Btw you can't name variables as `class`

Comment: @Metoniem it depends on how you are receiving the `obj` in reality. If you have specified it in a promise like this: `axios(...).then((response: {id: number}) => { let o = new Test(response.id); });` then TS won't throw an exception because types are correct. Please update the question to contain a real-world example.

Comment: Are you only seeing this at runtime? (To be expected, as all typings have been removed.) Like @Agney's example shows, it should fail when doing exactly what you've written.

Comment: I think what's confusing you is that Typescript will compile your code even if it contains errors. You'll get warnings during compilation, but it won't throw you any runtime errors

Comment: @Agney Whoops, it's early! Fixed the variable..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, Typescript typing is applying at compile time.

The data you retrieve from your `GET` request will always be treated as `any` unless you do something about it. Because Typescript have no way to determine what type the data is *(could be anything)*.

What you can do is strongly type the returns of your GET request. Then typescript will give you an error. But warning, it won't give you an error if the GET request doesn't return the wanted data.

```
const data: {
  id: string,
} = GET();

// ...
```

For validation, there are some plugins available, like https://github.com/hapijs/joi

---

I recommend you to define interfaces for every GET request, like :

```
interface GetUserR {
   users: {
     id: string,
     name: string,
   }[],
}

const users: GetUserR = await requester.GET('users');
```

This way you got autocompletion, errors are easy to spot and it's evolutive. Best would be to have your backend emit theses interfaces if you handle the front and the back.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. I suppose `The thing is, Typescript typing is applying at compile time.` Is enough to answer my question already. I'm fairly new to TS and I guess I expected it to compile with some additional code that would type check the given parameters. I do indeed handle both the front and back so I will adjust those accordingly :)